# HTC HD2 device emulator

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, htcsense, htc-hd2

I'm new to the Windows Mobile scene, but I have made a few Symbian apps before.  When I was making those apps the target device was always a Nokia, and Nokia is good about providing specific device emulators.  Despite my best search efforts the only emulator I can find for Windows Mobile 6.5 devices is in the SDK.  I want to develop apps for the HTC HD2 which does run Windows Mobile 6.5, but has a vastly different screen size and a touch interface with HTC Sense.  I want to include/build around the features of the HD2, but I am unsure how to efficiently and effectively do that without an HD2 device emulator unless I wanted to take a chance with my phone... which I do not.

**Where can I get an HD2 device emulator?**

**Any other thoughts?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only HTC could provide such an emulator, and I'm not aware of one.  You can [alter the settings for the existing emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289160(VS.71).aspx#grfvsdconfigurationsettings) to adjust the display size to match the HD2.  What exactly are you afraid of with using your actual hardware?  Real hardware is always a better target than emulation anyway.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  Very simple, can't believe I missed it.  As for why I am afraid of using my phone, I have just heard some horror stories, and I once had a scare with my 6600 where I thought I bricked it.  After all of this I have come to the crushing realization that I cannot develop apps for the HD2 (WM 6.5) in Visual Studio 2010 because VS2010 only supports WM7.0 or higher... Damm you Bill... Damm you...

Comment: Wish we could blame it on Bill.  Trust me, we're lobbying hard to get this remedied, it's just tought getting resource allocation for it.